# How to use git with XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I read the ["How to Create a CocoaPod in Swift"](http://www.raywenderlich.com/99386/create-cocoapod-swift) and I got stuck when I tried to push to git:

```
cd ~/Documents/Libraries/RWPickFlavor  
git init  
git add .  
git commit -m "Initial commit"  
git tag 0.1.0  
git remote add origin [Your RWPickFlavor Git URL]  
git push -u origin master --tags
```

when I execute the last instruction,the terminal outputs that I don't handle protocol '[https'

Note: My git version is 2.3.2,and Pod version is 0.38.0

Comment: `[Your RWPickFlavor Git URL]` in tutorial  is a placeholder, and you should use your real git repo address in its place.

Comment: I have already used my git URL,but it still tell me the same error

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you set up your remote URL correctly? You can check it with this command:

```
git remove -v
```

I suspect yours has square brackets in it, like this:

```
origin  [https://github.com/...git] (fetch)
origin  [https://github.com/...git] (push)
```

It should look something like this:

```
origin  https://github.com/...git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/...git (push)
```

Comment: `origin [https://github.com/KimLee2015/LeePods_oc.git] (fetch)`  `origin [https://github.com/KimLee2015/LeePods_oc.git] (push)`  This is what the terminal output,but I don't think it is wrong

Comment: There should be no square brackets. You can fix it with `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/KimLee2015/LeePods_oc.git`

Comment: `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/KimLee2015/LeePods_oc.git`  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: You are either not in the directory of your project or you delete the `.git` folder

Comment: I have already finished [http://www.raywenderlich.com/99386/create-cocoapod-swift]  MyStoreSearch is my Swift project,and the Pods contain SDWebImage.I also create the Bridging-Header.h,when input '#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"'  Xcode output that UIImageView+WebCache.h file not found

Answer (score 0):

You can download the GitHub App and push to repository without using termal/commandline

aslong as you have ticked git repo when you created the xcode project